# EditText in AlertDialog not focussed automatically on Android 9 (API 28)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

I have an `EditText` in an `AlertDialog`.

To show the soft keyboard when the `AlertDialog` is shown I call

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

before calling

```
alertDialog.show();
```

This has been working fine so far. But the same code does not work on Android 9 (API 28). It seems that the `EditText`does not get focussed automatically and therefore the soft keyboard is not shown.

How can I fix this so that the soft keyboard is shown automatically when the `AlertDialog` is shown on Android 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue by simply calling

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

before showing the alert.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions on it:

**First:**

```
<EditText ...>
  <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

**Second:**

```
<Your Layout 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" />
```

Ie: below Two lines you can add it on your parent layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**Third:**

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
```

**Forth:**

```
<EditText ...>
  android:focusable="true"
</EditText>
```

And many multiple ways are there all are preferable.

Comment: Unfortunately non of your solutions is working here. Did you try it on Android 9?

Comment: OK, @kaolick let me check alternate solution on it.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I tried your solutions at the wrong part of my code. Sorry for that.